# Child process doesn't modify statistics in parent process

Tags: c, unix, process, semaphore, shared-memory

I'm working on a C application that involves multiple processes, both child processes and the parent process, and I'm trying to share statistics between them using shared memory and semaphores. However, I'm encountering an issue with my code where the child process doesn't seem to correctly modify the shared statistics in the parent process, which is preventing me from printing them accurately.

In main, I created and attached shared memory:

```
stats_shm_id = create_shared_memory(SHM_STATS_KEY, sizeof(Statistics));
stats = (Statistics *)attach_shared_memory(stats_shm_id);
```

The init function does:

```
stats = (Statistics *)malloc(sizeof(Statistics));
stats->shared_data_1 = 0;
stats->shared_data_2 = 0;
```

The print function does:

```
printf("%d",stats->shared_data1);
printf("%d",stats->shared_data2);
```

My goal is to have the child process modify the shared statistics in the parent process so that they can be printed accurately. However, it seems that the changes made by the child process aren't reflected in the parent process when I call the print_statistics() function. I've verified that semaphores are being used correctly to synchronize access to the statistics.

Could someone kindly help me understand what might be going wrong? Could this be a synchronization issue? What steps should I consider to troubleshoot and resolve this problem?

Thank you in advance for any help and suggestions!

Comment: `printf(stats->shared_data1);` Do you mean `printf("%d\n", stats->shared_data1);`?

Comment: Add the compiler options `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors` and fix everything. Even without `-Werror` I would be surprised if `gcc` or `clang` would compile this.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Of course, I simplified things to ask the question. In any case, I've added the flags, and I don't have any errors in my program.

Comment: @DavidRanieri yes, of course

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have added the correct original code nonetheless.

Comment: Ok, but that's too much irrelevant code.  Narrow it down into a  program as short as possible that people can compile and that displays the problems you have. See [mre].

Comment: Your data structtures contain pointers, so can't usefully be used with shared memory -- each process will attach the shared memory at different addresses. You need to use offsets from the start of the shared memory block rather than pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could someone kindly help me understand what might be going wrong?

Your `initialize_statistics()` function sets the global `stats` variable to point to (unshared) dynamically allocated memory.  This foils the previous work to set up and attach to a shared memory segment.  The processes are not, in fact, using shared memory at all.

Comment: In the main function of my program, I have used the shmget function to create shared memory segments and shmat to attach them, both in the parent and child processes.

Comment: Oh no, you're right! I used malloc in the initialization function, after doing the attach. If I move the malloc before the attach, everything works correctly. Thank you! :)

Comment: I'm glad to have helped, @chiara_tummi, but you don't seem to have fully grasped the point: you should not be doing the `malloc()` *at all*.

Comment: I added the struct Statistics in the question, can you give me an advice on how I should initialize this shared memory?

Comment: Your data structtures contain pointers, so can't usefully be used with shared memory -- each process will attach the shared memory at different addresses.  You need to use offsets from the start of the shared memory block rather than pointers.

Comment: ... and one way of accomplishing that is by using real arrays.  It looks like you have in mind to dynamically allocate memory to use as arrays in conjunction with that data structure, but inasmuch as everything associated with the statistics needs to reside inside the shared memory, you cannot use the standard memory allocation functions for that.  You could conceivably obtain a much larger shared memory segment and do your own bespoke dynamic management of its contents, but it would be *much* easier to just declare large-enough-for-all-supported-cases arrays, @chiara_tummi.

Comment: Your help was invaluable, thank you so much, I was stuck for days